# Network classes vs subnetting/supernetting

Tags: subnet

I'm studying for my network+ exam and I just had a general question. Since we can subnet and supernet networks, why is there a need to classify them as a,b and c to begin with?

Comment: While we may all still *say* class A, B, C, we *MEAN* /8, /16, and /24. It's not correct, but people still do it. I suspect your lame Network+ class is doing it, too.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

Network address classes are dead (please let them rest in peace), killed in 1993 (two years *before* the commercial Internet in 1995) by RFCs 1517, 1518, and 1519, which defined CIDR (*Classless* Inter-Domain Routing). We have not had network address classes in this century.

If that exam is testing your knowledge of network address classes, it is woefully out of date, or it may be that your study material that is out of date.

The very last (appropriately so) section of [this two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) explains about network address classes (historic purposes only). Please learn to properly subnet before polluting your thought processes with network address classes.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and explanation.

Comment: If an answer helps you, you should accept it so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.